# Binding imported files to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, bind

I'm trying to bind a list of my class into a `ListView`. I've tried many issues.
There is my c# Code witch show how I define:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // L’intervalle entre chaque tick du timer sera d’une seconde
     timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // A chaque tick, on déclenche l’évènement timer_Tick
     MyMP3LIST = new List<ListGrid>();
     ListM.DataContext = MyMP3LIST; // ListM = ListView name
     // I've tried : ListM.ItemSource = MyMP3LIST;
}
```

When try to bind :

```
ListGrid l = new ListGrid(); // My Class
l.IconUri = imagemp3.Source;
l.Title = Ftitle;
l.Length = duration;
l.Album = Falbum;
l.Composer = Fcomposer;
l.Path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
MyMP3LIST.Add(l);
```

My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListM" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MyMP3LIST}"
   Margin="-3,-0.877,-4,-15.925" SelectionChanged="ListM_SelectionChanged">
```

Just the first imported file is display into the `ListView`.

Comment: I don't know if the issue is due to your collection, be sure to use an ObservableCollection<yourclass> and be sure that your element class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If the elements do not appear maybe you need to define the Item template for your list View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After populating `MyMP3LIST` Change this:

```
ListM.DataContext = MyMP3LIST;
```

To this:

```
this.DataContext = MyMP3LIST;
```

And also change this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListM" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MyMP3LIST}" ../>
```

To this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListM" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" .../>
```

Also in your `ListView` you need `ItemTemplate` to show data. For example:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListM" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />     
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" />    
          ... 
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView>
```

**Edit:** Based on your comments that you said you want to add item with an `OpenFileDialog` and you want to update your `ListView`, `MyMP3LIST` should be `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<ListGrid> MyMP3LIST = new ObservableCollection<ListGrid>();
```

Comment: Now it's ok, i see just one of my item.. I can't see the second item when i import it

Comment: @JimmyJames...You mean that adding items is in a `Button_Click` event? Well once you set the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` to the `MyMP3LIST` after changing the source your `ListView` doesn't updated. you should use `ObservableCollection` if you want to see the updated `ListView` after adding items.

Comment: I mean adding item with an openfiledialog, i can select my music and after i want to see it in the ListView

Comment: @JimmyJames...`MyMP3LIST` should be `ObservableCollection<ListGrid> MyMP3LIST = new ObservableCollection<ListGrid>();`

Comment: Works FINE ! I use `ListM.DataContext = MyMP3LIST;` instead of `this.DataContext = MyMP3LIST;` and i've declared `public ObservableCollection<ListGrid> MyMP3LIST = new ObservableCollection<ListGrid>();`... Thanks you sir !

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the double answer but comments do not allow code.
This is just a sample so I'm not sure if all the properties are exact, but it should look like this:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Margin="0" 
               >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldName1}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldName2}" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldName3}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FieldName4}" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The Item template can be defined with any kind of WPF control you like for your properties.